# Push changed project structure into git

Tags: git, maven, maven-module

I have currently single project without modules in Git.
But now I do some changes and one of these changes is split project into maven modules and created maven inheritance.

Can you tell me please if can I simply push it into `master` branch or should I something extra do?
I wouldn't make mess in git with that push.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your maven project shifts from a mono-module to a multi-module is of no consequence for a Git repo: you can still add, commit and push as usual, as long as your `.gitignore` is well configured: you would not want to add maven module `target/` folders.

There is only an issue if you were to isolate those maven modules into their own Git repo, in which case a [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) approach might be needed.

But as long as you are talking about *maven* modules (which are a way of restructuring your sources), you can add them to your Git repo and push.